# Java Applet - Convert File to String

Tags: java, string, file, applet

How can convert a certain file into in a String? And then from that String to get the original file? This needs to realize it using Java.

It would be greate an example of code or a link to a tutorial.

**Have to converted an entire File (not thecontent) in the String and then the String to the File.**

Thanks.

Comment: why did you flag this question with 'applet'. In most cases, you cannot read or write a file from an Applet.

Comment: Because I need this in a applet application.

Comment: hm, do you need to convert a filename-(to/from)-file, or file _contents_ (to/from) file

Comment: Have to converted an entire File (not thecontent) in the String and then the String to the File.

Comment: again - what is the _entire file_, if not its content?

Comment: The aplication need to convert into string not only text file but any file.

Comment: You shouldn't want to convert binary files to string.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NB: In both cases below you will have to *digitally sign* your applet, so that it is granted permissions to read/write from/to the file system!

If you can use external libraries, use [Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) (you will have to sign these jars as well)

[`FileUtils.readFileToString(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29)

[`FileUtils.writeStringToFile(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)

If you can't, you can see [this tutorial](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42).

This is for text files - but if you want to read binary files (.png for instance), you should *not* read it as string. Instead read it as `byte[]` and use [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) -

encode: [`String base64String = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(byteArray));`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

decode: `byte[] originalBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(string.getByte());`

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a string format for storing binary data.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the applet must be signed to access the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getFileContent(File file) throws IOException
{
FileReader in=new FileReader(file);
StringWriter w= new StringWriter();
char buffer[]=new char[2048];
int n=0;
while((n=in.read(buffer))!=-1)
 {
 w.write(buffer, 0, n);
 }
w.flush();
in.close();
return w.toString();
}

public static void toFileContent(String s,File file) throws IOException
{
FileWriter f=new FileWriter(file);
f.write(s);
f.flush();
f.close();
}
```